# Sending buffer to HID with python

Tags: python, hex, buffer

I want to send a buffer to an HID, I have trouble making the buffer, here's my code:

```
buffer = [0x00]*20
print(buffer)
buffer[0:10] = {0x00,0x00,0x11,0x06,0x00,0x04,0x1A,0x00,0x00,0x0b,0xb8}
print(buffer)
```

the output is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 4, 6, 11, 17, 184, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

but when I use this:

```
buffer[0] = 0x00
buffer[1] = 0x00
buffer[2] = 0x11
buffer[3] = 0x06
buffer[4] = 0x00
buffer[5] = 0x04
buffer[6] = 0x1A
buffer[7] = 0x00
buffer[8] = 0x00
buffer[9] = 0x0b
buffer[10] = 0xb8
```

The output is:
    [0, 0, 17, 6, 0, 4, 26, 0, 0, 11, 184, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

I also should convert from decimal to hex, for example 1000 to hex.

```
print(hex(1000))
```

It gives:

```
0x3e8
```

I want to have :

```
03 E8
```

How can I have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you wrote these lines:

```
buffer[0:10] = {0x00,0x00,0x11,0x06,0x00,0x04,0x1A,0x00,0x00,0x0b,0xb8}
print(buffer)
```

You used braces {}, so you assigned a ***set*** to the slice [0:10] of the list `buffer`. And you must know that:

- a set is not ordered,
- a set does not store duplicated values

So the assignment replaces the values with indices 0 to 9 (so the 10 first values) with the unordered 7 values 0x00,0x11,0x06,0x04,0x1A,0x0b,0xb8. That's what you observe.

Secondly, when you wrote lines like `buffer[0] = 0x00`, you assign directly the first element of the list to the value 0x00, so there is no surprise.

Finally, to answer your last question and print "1000" as "03 E8", I propose you this solution:

```
import re
print(" ".join(re.findall(r'..',(1000).to_bytes(2,'big').hex().upper())))
```

Comment: How ca I have 0x03 0xE8